# Melodic minor Major 9 chords

Tags: chord-theory

While researching melodic minor chords I came across Am(M9). If this is a true chord what notes are in it? My guess is A-C-E-G#-B.

Not sure if one plays this on a piano… probably something for a guitar?

Comment: I've always thought of it as a mix of I and V - not technically accurate, but easy to find in any key that way. And it could equally be found in the harmonic minor scale. .

Answer (score 4):

The notes in "Am maj9" are A-C-E-G#-B. I use that chord quite often, on piano and guitar as well. It sounds really nice as a final chord in a song that's in the key of A minor. Or in the middle of a descending voice line "A-G#-G-F#...". Do you know the song "Stairway to Heaven" by Led Zeppelin? The second chord in the famous progression could be called "Am maj9".

Comment: Interesting … also 'Curiouser and curiouser!'. Will revisit Stairway ...

Comment: It's also sometimes called the "James Bond Chord" :) It's heavily used in the movies for "mysterious suspense". Listen for it at end of the main theme for example.

Comment: @DickRitchie You can also think of it as an E/G# or an Am + E polychord. The chords from Stairway are very useful in many different situations, if you can see their functions in a more general context. The fourth chord D/F# is another great one, if you play it with two fingers barre style x9777x, and not like xx4232. I use that in almost every song.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the AmM9 chord does exist and your guess with A, C, E, G♯, B is correct.

Of course you can also play it on the piano if you find any use for it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Am(maj9) is an Am triad - A, C, E - plus the maj7 - G# - (that's what the 'maj' part of the chord name tells us) plus the 9th - B - (that's what the '9' part of the name tells us).

So, A, C, E, G#, B.  Good on guitar.  Good on piano.  Good on anything, really!

Often used non-functionally to spice up a final tonic chord in a minor key.

(In a major key try A13(#11).   Think of it as a polychord, B over A7 if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also often find m(maj9) chords written as min9(maj7) or mi9(ma7). This model treats the chord as a 9th chord rather than a 7th chord, with the maj7 as an alteration. Same exact notes though.